# How to Take month wise dump in oracle 10G?

Tags: oracle, export, scheduled-tasks

I have database. I need to take back up of table month wise. so how to take backup in month wise in oracle 10G?

Comment: Anybody can answer this question?

Answer (score 0):

You don't mean "backup".  Backup implies recovery, and a monthly dump is no good for recovery purposes.  That's why Nature gave us [RMAN](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/backup.112/e10642/toc.htm).

The Oracle export and import tool is called Data Pump.  We can run this as an external command or with a PL/SQL API.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_overview.htm#SUTIL100).

Running a monthly export requires a scheduling tool.  Use an OS command such as `cron` to run a shell script invoking the command line `expdp` or the built-in DBMS_SCHEDULER to run a stored proc using DBMS_DATAPUMP.